# Use Python script to output string?

Tags: python, authentication, output

I've been making a simple program in Python which might serve as a simple sort of program for cracking passwords (this is just for fun in school, don't think I'm trying to hack or anything). The problem I've run into is that I have no idea how to make Python output as I want... As of the moment I only have it print the values it's generating.

Is it even possible to make python output a variable or string that it generates to log on as a user or something? Or, taking a step back from purely trying to log on, is there any way for Python to output a string that is generated within the script to a different source (just as an example, say, output the string generated from the Python script onto the address bar of a web browser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look you can do almost everything with python, this example opens www.google.com in your
default browser:

```
import os

webString = "http://www.google.com/"
os.system("open "+webString)
```

with `os.system(someString)` you can run any command (someString) as you would if you were in a terminal.

Comment: So by using os.system(blah blah blah), that will work as if i were entering those commands on the command prompt? Or i could use this to preform the same functions as if i were using a batch file?

Comment: yes... but you have to take into account that it doesn't work the same in all operative systems.

Answer (score 0):

the most common way to print text is by using the 'print' function. repr provides the internal representation of a value, in this way you could determine if the value was a string (using repr would yeild '...' not ...).

```
my_string = "hello"
print(my_string)

next_string = "there"
print(repr(next_string))
```

Produces

```
>>> 
hello
'there'
```

Another example is this

```
import string

for i,letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase,1):
    print(str(i)+" : "+letter)
```

Which outputs the letters of the alphabet and their index.

i.e

```
>>> 
1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
```

As you can see, print allows you to output the value of a variable (it doesn't only work for strings!). These variables can have their values assigned during runtime and hence you can print content dynamically.

If you wanted to create a seperate log file:

```
def getLog():
    return "yadayadaydada"

log = getLog()

with open('f.txt','a+') as f:
    f.write(log)
```

Would create an external text file called 'f.txt' and append the values provided to f.write (in any calls you may have made), in this case producing:

```
yadayadaydada
```

Comment: thanks for the great explanations, althought they weren't quite what I was looking for :P

Comment: Sorry about that, could you be more specific (i.e give some use cases) so I can have another go at answering your question?

Comment: think that i've found what I want from Balz's answer (if it can work like writing a batch file) but thanks for the help none the less.